# Cannot connect to Parse Cloud

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, samsung-mobile

I am currently making an application using Parse in Android. I downloaded the default Test Object code and tried it out but the it doesn't work. I use a Samsung Note 4. The application works on other phones but not on this one. Any ideas would be helpful.
P.S I have added the key, Application java file, used ParseUser, etc. 
Thanks :)

EDIT: Here is the stack trace:

```
10-18 16:34:51.512: I/System.out(28024): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 16:34:51.562: I/System.out(28024): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
10-18 16:34:52.962: I/System.out(28024): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 16:34:52.972: I/System.out(28024): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
10-18 16:34:55.762: I/System.out(28024): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 16:34:55.872: I/System.out(28024): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
10-18 16:35:01.412: I/System.out(28024): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 16:35:01.522: I/System.out(28024): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
10-18 16:35:12.602: I/System.out(28024): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 16:35:12.752: I/System.out(28024): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024): com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:321)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:159)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:153)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:825)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to api.parse.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:238)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1194)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseURLConnectionHttpClient.executeInternal(ParseURLConnectionHttpClient.java:51)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:158)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParsePlugins$1.intercept(ParsePlugins.java:115)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseHttpClient.execute(ParseHttpClient.java:122)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:150)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:147)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:825)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:816)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:628)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:639)
10-18 16:35:12.752: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:731)
10-18 16:35:12.762: W/System.err(28024):    at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:719)
10-18 16:35:12.762: W/System.err(28024):    ... 4 more
10-18 16:35:12.762: W/System.err(28024): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-18 16:35:12.762: W/System.err(28024):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
10-18 16:35:12.762: W/System.err(28024):    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Where doesn't it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please add error messages, what you've tried to isolate the problem. Please add a link to the "default Test Object code" or include it in your post.

Comment: I keep getting ParseRequestException I/o failure. I checked and there is some issue connecting to parse. I dont exactly know what but it only happens for my Note 4 as of now. I checked in an Asus Zenphone and the old Galaxy S3. Both work fine. :/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I found the answer. The problem was with an ad block i was using. It re-routes all unknown server responses to the localhost itself and parse was considered one of them. So if anyone has the same issue, just revert your hosts file.